# Python featuretools difference by data group

Tags: python, data-science, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, featuretools

I'm trying to use featuretools to calculate time-series functions. Specifically, I'd like to subtract current(x) from previous(x) by a group-key (user_id), but I'm having trouble in adding this kind of relationship in the entityset.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "user_id": [i % 2 for i in range(0, 6)],
    'x': range(0, 6),
    'time': pd.to_datetime(['2014-1-1 04:00', '2014-1-1 05:00', 
                            '2014-1-1 06:00', '2014-1-1 08:00', '2014-1-1 10:00', '2014-1-1 12:00'])
     })

print(df.to_string())
       user_id  x                time
0        0      0 2014-01-01 04:00:00
1        1      1 2014-01-01 05:00:00
2        0      2 2014-01-01 06:00:00
3        1      3 2014-01-01 08:00:00
4        0      4 2014-01-01 10:00:00
5        1      5 2014-01-01 12:00:00


es = ft.EntitySet(id='test')
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id='data', dataframe=df,
                         variable_types={
                             'user_id': ft.variable_types.Categorical,
                             'x': ft.variable_types.Numeric,
                             'time': ft.variable_types.Datetime
                         },
                         make_index=True, index='index',
                         time_index='time'
                         )
```

I then try to invoke dfs, but I can't get the relationship right...

```
fm, fl = ft.dfs(
    target_entity="data",
    entityset=es,
    trans_primitives=["diff"]
)
print(fm.to_string())
       user_id  x  DIFF(x)
index                     
0            0  0      NaN
1            1  1      1.0
2            0  2      1.0
3            1  3      1.0
4            0  4      1.0
5            1  5      1.0
```

But what I'd actually want to get is the difference by user. That is, from the last value for each user:

```
       user_id  x  DIFF(x)
index                     
0            0  0      NaN
1            1  1      NaN
2            0  2      2.0
3            1  3      2.0
4            0  4      2.0
5            1  5      2.0
```

How do I get this kind of relationship in featuretools? I've tried several tutorial but to no avail. I'm stumped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the question. You can get the expected output by normalizing an entity for users and applying a group by transform primitive. I'll go through a quick example using this data.

```
user_id  x                time
      0  0 2014-01-01 04:00:00
      1  1 2014-01-01 05:00:00
      0  2 2014-01-01 06:00:00
      1  3 2014-01-01 08:00:00
      0  4 2014-01-01 10:00:00
      1  5 2014-01-01 12:00:00
```

First, create the entity set and normalize an entity for the users.

```py
es = ft.EntitySet(id='test')

es.entity_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df,
    entity_id='data',
    make_index=True,
    index='index',
    time_index='time',
)

es.normalize_entity(
    base_entity_id='data',
    new_entity_id='users',
    index='user_id',
)
```

Then, apply the group by transform primitive in DFS.

```py
fm, fl = ft.dfs(
    target_entity="data",
    entityset=es,
    groupby_trans_primitives=["diff"],
)

fm.filter(regex="DIFF", axis=1)
```

You should get the difference by user.

```
       DIFF(x) by user_id
index
0                     NaN
1                     NaN
2                     2.0
3                     2.0
4                     2.0
5                     2.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wrecking my brains about that one. I wasn't familiar with groupby_trans primitives. Cheers!